# Incorrect syntax near "," - Adapter.Update

Tags: sql, adapter

I have a query which pulls data from 2 tables, such as:

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2,t2.col2,t2.col3 
from Table1 t1,Table2 t2 
where t1.col1=t2.col1
```

I use an adapter to fill a dataset.

I display only the fields from Table2 in a grid and allow the user to update them.

I have created a SqlCommand for update operations and use this command to call the adapter.update on Table2 only.

The update fails giving the "Incorrect syntact near ','" error against the row that was updated by the user.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: The SQL looks good to me... can we maybe see the complete code that's using the query?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JOIN-Statement`:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2, t2.col3 
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Comment: it's only a difference of sintax. The result is the same

Comment: the query that he shows hasn't a syntax error really, I think the problem is in another place that he's not showing us

Comment: of course.. but I think some OP's think that we use a crystal ball to answer the questions

Comment: Thank you all for your response! I figured the error out. My update command was not properly constructed.